# How to find iOS version distribution of your app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How do you check how many people are using your app via, say, iOS 3 versus iOS 4? How did [this developer](http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/2011/03/is-it-worth-supporting-ios-3-in-2011.html), for example, make a graph of his version distribution? I would like to know my personal version distribution to better allocate my development time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some external sources that you can use for this tracking, which also provide analytics reporting.  I have been using [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com) in my apps, which is free.  It was extremely easy to work with, in my experience.

Comment: So... the problem is my app is already released. I will have to use Localytics on my *next* version. Why didn't Apple build any sort of analytics like Google? Android has a ton more analytics - country, OS, device, language.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the the iOS version of a device by using:

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`.

Then you have to send that info back to your server.

Answer (score 0):

We've been using [flurry](http://www.flurry.com) for analytics in our apps and we've been really happy with it. It keeps great track of the version distribution, but also allows us to track just about any event we want just by dropping in a line of code. Anyway, I'm sure there are many other great options out there, but that one's definitely worth checking out... and it's free.